# eventemitter.emit method doesn't return in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc, eventemitter, event-loop

I have a problem using eventemitter.emit method.

Basically this is what I want to do. I have a long running process (CPU bounded) that generates output objects, and since this is CPU bounded process i run it as a separate process using fork().

```
class Producer extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
       this.on('MyEvent', this.produce);
    }

    produce(input) {
        var output = longRunningProcess();

        this.emit('MyEvent, output);
        process.send(output);
    }
}

var producer = new Producer();
producer.emit('MyEvent', 0); // To kick off the execution
```

And once each output is generated, I want to send it to the parent process. And also use it to emit an event to produce another object and so on.

Now, the problem is that the `process.send(output)` doesn't seem to be executed. I can see the outputs being printed in the console one after one. But the parent doesn't seem to be receiving anything from the child process. In my understanding, nodejs event loop shouldn't pick up a new task until it finishes the current one and the stack is empty, but this is not the case here.

So can you guys help me with this?

**Edit**: Parent process code

```
this.producer = ChildProcess.fork('.path/to/produer.js'silent: true });
this.producer.on('message', (data) => {
    this.miningProcess.send({ type: "StopMining", body: 0 });
});
```

Comment: Also, please show the relevant portion of the receiving code in the parent process as that could also be where the problem is.

Comment: In addition, this won't work properly: `this.on('MyEvent', this.produce);`  You would need `this.on('MyEvent', this.produce.bind(this));`

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop.  You do `producer.emit('MyEvent')` to kick things off.  The event handler in your constructor receives that and calls `this.produce()` which then does `this.emit('MyEvent, output);` again which is received by the event handler in your constructor which starts it all over again - infinite loop.

Comment: @jfriend00, Added parent logic. For now it is pretty simple.

Comment: Infinite loops often don't work in nodejs because you don't let the event loop process anything which can stall networking.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for answering. When the produce emitts 'MyEvent', It should schedule a the produce callback to be executed. But the current function should finish and process.send(message) should be called. At least this is how I understand it. So in this case, each produce will schedule a new call in the event queue. but the current one should finish and process.send should be called.

Comment: Nope, .emit() is synchronous.  There's no scheduling and no cycles for the event queue in what you show.  Even outbound networking may get stalled.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for the clarification. That actually makes sense. So what is the recommendation here? using something like settimeout(callback, 0) or is there another class that will do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you may be starving the event loop (never giving it any cycles to processing incoming events) which can wreck the ability  to process networking, even outbound networking.  I'd suggest that you start the next iteration only after the `process.send()` has completed.

```
class Producer extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this.on('MyEvent', this.produce.bind(this));
    }

    produce(input) {
        let output = longRunningProcess();

        process.send(output, () => {
            // When the send finishes, start the next iteration
            // This should allow the node.js event queue to process things
            this.emit('MyEvent, output);
        });
    }
}

var producer = new Producer();
producer.emit('MyEvent', 0); // To kick off the execution
```

Other comments of note:

1. You need `this.produce.bind(this)` on your event handler instead of just `this.produce` to make sure the right `this` value is set when that function is called.
2. Keep in mind that `eventEmitter.emit()` is synchronous.  It does not allow the event queue to process events and `eventEmitter` events do not go through the event queue.
3. This code assumes that the `process.send()` callback is called asynchronously and gives the event loop enough chances to process any events that are waiting.  It also makes sure the interprocess message is completely sent before you start the next CPU intensive iteration which will temporarily block the event queue processing again.  This way, you are sure the whole communication is done before blocking the event queue again.
4. You probably could have made things work with an appropriately places `setTimeout()` to kick off the next iteration, but I think it's more reliable to make sure the interprocess messaging is done before kicking off the next iteration.
5. FYI, if you're not using the `EventEmitter` you derive from for anything other than is shown here, then it isn't really needed.  You could just call methods on your object directly rather than using `EventEmitter` events.

Comment: Added several comments to explain some things further.